# Calculating 2022 NDVI time series

Tags: ndvi, sentinel-2, satellite, time-series

I calculated seasonal NDVI Time series (1 image for each season) from 2017 to 2022 using Sentinel-2 L1C images (which I converted to L2A using Sen2Cor), the first 5 years where ok, but the last 3 seasons of 2022 didn't follow the same seasonality, the same problem occured in 3 different study regions.

What could it be?

This is the time series:

[image]

Comment: Did you take into account the changes in the processing baseline that took place in January 2022? https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/processing-baseline

Comment: @HMSP I used sen2cor ver 2.11 for all images I didn't specify the baseline and I don't know how, to prevent the non hamonization of images I downloaded all images as L1C ans converted it all with the same tool

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google earth engine then u may need to use Harmonized data which takes into account the processing baseline changes into account. the snippet--‘COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED’